# Find the amount of palm extract that minimizes the cost per kilometer

Tags: calculus, operations-research

> After much research, ***Palmoil***, a mixture of palm oil (P) and diesel (D), was created. A liter of palm oil costs \$0.30 and a liter of diesel costs \$0.50. However, for a liter of ***Palmoil*** with $x \in [0,1]$ liters of palm oil the performance is $\frac{10}{1+x}$ kilometers per liter.
>
> Determine the amount of palm oil (P) that minimizes the cost per kilometer .

My doubt is that when I create the equation I can not find minimum but just maximum.

Here is what I am doing so far:
$\frac{\textrm{km}}{\textrm{l}}=(\frac{10}{1+x}).\frac{1}{x}$

cost per kilometer =$((\frac{10}{1+x}).\frac{1}{x})$.

Price=$((\frac{10}{1+x}).\frac{1}{x})(0,3x+(1-x)0,5)=\frac{-2x+5}{x+x^2}$

So the $x=\frac{5}{2}$ is a max price not minimum price. My conclusion is so far that this mixture is completely wrong. Am I right?

Comment: Your calculation $\frac{10}{1+x}\frac{1}{x}$ does not make sense (it gives you the number of kilometres per litre of *Palmoil* per litre of palm oil.) You are already given the number of kilometres per litre of *Palmoil* ; it is $\frac{10}{1+x}$. To get the cost per kilometre, you need to calculate the cost per litre of *Palmoil* and divide by the kilometres per liter of *Palmoil*.

Answer (score 3):

Your notation is a bit confusing... so I could have some inputs wrong, please correct me if there are mistakes.

We wish to optimize $x$, the palm oil fraction in **Palmoil**.  We are given that:

(1) For each liter of **Palmoil**, we get $\frac{10}{1+x}$ km of performance.

(2) Since palm oil costs \$0.3/liter and diesel costs \$0.5/liter, the cost of **Palmoil** is $0.3x + 0.5(1-x)$ dollars per liter.

Thus, the cost per kilometer of **Palmoil** with palm oil fraction $x$ is given by:

$$ c(x) = \left[ \frac{1+x}{10} \frac{\textrm{L}}{\textrm{km}} \right] \left[ \left(\frac{3x}{10} + \frac{1-x}{2}\right) \frac{$}{L} \right] \\
=  \left[ \left(\frac{1+x}{10}\right) \frac{\textrm{L}}{\textrm{km}} \right] \left[ \left(\frac{5-2x}{10} \right) \frac{$}{L} \right] \\
= \left( \frac{(1+x)(5-2x)}{100}\right) \frac{$}{\textrm{km}} \\
= \frac{1}{100} (5 + 3x - 2x^2) \frac{$}{\textrm{km}}$$

We want to minimize $c(x)$.  However, $c''(x) = -4/100 < 0$, so there is no local minimum.  Any critical points will be a local maximum.  Thus, the minimum must occur at one of the endpoints of the domain of $x$, which must be between $0$ and $1$.

$c(0) = \frac{5}{100}$ and $c(1) = \frac{6}{100}$.

Thus, the optimal cost to performance ratio is $x = 0$, which means **Palmoil** should just be entirely diesel... ha.

Comment: I think you did not understand the question. Have a look at my answer

Comment: I was wrong. My mistake. Sorry